# dynamically setting keyframes stroke-dashoffset

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyframe

Hi I am trying to create a circular percentage bar, it works with hard set values however it needs to be dynamically set, i assumed that i could set the styling properties in my script but im not sure how to access it.

html for percentage circle:

```
  <div class="percentBox">
            <div class="OuterCircle">
                    <div class="InnerCircle">
                            <div id="number">
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                    <defs>
                            <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                                    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                                    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                            </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </svg>
            </div>
```

heres my keyframes styling:

```
@keyframes anim{
100%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}}
```

css class styling:

```
.OuterCircle {
width: 120px;
height:120px;
border-radius:50%;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
           -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);}


.InnerCircle {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
border-radius:50%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
               -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7),
               -0.5px -0.5px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
               0.5px 0.5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
               0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);}

circle{
fill:none;
stroke: url(#GradientColor);
stroke-width: 20px;
stroke-dasharray: 472;
stroke-dashoffset: 472;
animation: anim 2s linear forwards;}
```

and heres my script:

```
<script>
    let number = document.getElementById("number");
    let counter = 0;
    val keyframe =document.getElementById("keyframes");
    keyframe.setStroke-offset(VARIABLE)
    setInterval(() => {
            if(counter == VARIABLE){
                    clearInterval
            } else {
            counter += 1;
            number.innerHTML = counter + "%"
            }
    }, 20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### AFTER QUESTION UPDATE:

---

**You can not access keyframes in JavaScript** but as per the updated HTML and CSS, we can have your functionality in below manner:

- I have also updated some of the styles (positioning)

```js
let number = document.getElementById("number");
let circle = document.getElementById("circle");
let counter = 0;
let maxCounter = 100;

const totalOffset = 472;
let currentOffset = totalOffset
const strokeDashoffsetSteps = totalOffset / maxCounter;

let interval = setInterval(() => {
  // update counter
  counter += 1;
  // update currentOffset
  currentOffset -= strokeDashoffsetSteps
  if(counter === maxCounter){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  // update text
  number.innerHTML = counter + "%"; 
  // update dashOffset
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = currentOffset;
}, 20);
```

```css
.percentBox {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.OuterCircle {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
    -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.InnerCircle {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
    -0.5px -0.5px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
    0.5px 0.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
    0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: url(#GradientColor);
  stroke-width: 20px;
  stroke-dasharray: 472;
  stroke-dashoffset: 472;
  animation: anim 2s linear forwards;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Circle Progress Bar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="percentBox">
    <div class="OuterCircle">
      <div class="InnerCircle">
        <div id="number">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <circle id="circle" cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### BEFORE QUESTION UPDATE:

---

You can not access keyframes in JavaScript but you can read your CSS file and parse your keyframes to get the actual data in JS or you can write the whole logic JS and I guess that'd be easy.

You can access strokeDashoffset using `element.style.strokeDashoffset` easily.
Please execute the below example for the same.

```js
const progress = document.querySelector('.progress');
console.log(progress.style.strokeDashoffset);

let offset = 0;
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (offset === 300) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  progress.style.strokeDashoffset = offset++;
}, 10);
```

```css
.progress {
  padding: 10px;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 15px;
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg">
  <path class="progress" d="m10,10 h300" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation however that is not quite what i was asking, to make it a little clearer ill add more of the css and the actual html structure i am using

Comment: @shinyest I have updated the code as per your question. I hope this helps :)

Comment: its very close thank you the problem is the amount of circle filled in needs to match the percentage e.g. 65% should have 65% of the circle filled in, is there no way to adjust the keyframe offset rather then the circles offset, would be alot more readable - when i do that by changing the value myself it exhibits excactly what i want to do however the percentage will change depending on other data the page loads

Comment: wait the offsets make a little more sense, the soloution works thank you! But, i would still like to know if you kenw how to do by modfying the keyrame value rather then the circles stroke-dashoffset